# Responsive height to a div?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

http://shrineweb.in/other-files/clients/markalves21/responsive/html/index.html

In link above, blue navigation is responsive in width, but not in height. I don't know what I am doing wrong, I have set min-height.

Here is the markup:

```
<div id="menu">

<!--the navigation/menu-->
<nav>
    <ul><!--un-ordered list with list items and child list items if the menuis to have a drop down-->
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="aboutus.html">About Us</a>
        <ul>
        <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li><!--child menu-->
        </ul>
        </li>
    <li><a href="contactus.html">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li>News
    <ul>
    <li><a href="clubnews.html">Club News</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>The Pitch
    <ul>
    <li><a href="plan.html">Plan</a></li>
    <li><a href="location.html">Location</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Teams
    <ul>
    <li><a href="under15.html">Under 15</a></li>
    <li><a href="under16.html">Under 16</a></li>
    <li><a href="under18.html">Under 18</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Matches
    <ul>
    <li><a href="fixtures.html">Fixtures</a></li>
    <li><a href="tables.html">Tables</a></li>
    <li><a href="results.html">Results</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Help
    <ul>
    <li><a href="askaq.html">Ask a Question</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ's</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

</div>
```

And here is the css:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1px) and (max-width: 2000px) {
#header {
width: 100%;
}
#header img {
width: 100%;
}
#menu {
color: #fff;
background: #4E84FE;
margin: 0px auto;
width: 100%;
min-height: 43px;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `(min-width:1px)`?

Comment: I don't think its responsive.. I could still see scrollbar at the bottom on window resize..

Comment: This whole markup and styling have nothing to do with responsive. In order to be honest, your width isn't responsive too. The scaling by change the screen-size isn't present. you menu-div scaling but the elements inside doesn't. Two things are quiet important in RWD , clever breakpoints and no fix pixel usage.

Comment: Those breakpoints you use never trigger in any case. But your webside should transform by those points. I would use a valuable Framework like [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com).

Comment: Adding `height: auto;` worked.
But as @Rishabh Shah mentioned, there is a horizontal scrollbar at the bottom on window resize. Why is that showing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following CSS properties to #menu

```
overflow: hidden;
height: auto;
```

Note that you may want to add a thin white border around the drop down or adjust the shade of blue because it starts to blend right in with the second row of the menu bar. Another option would be to use a media query to convert your written out menu to a drop down or another form of mobile friendly menu for small screens.

Also, I would suggest applying these styles as classes rather than id's (.menu). It is the proper way to handle this kind of thing.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. However, there is still a horizontal scroll bar showing. I have updated the files on server. Could you tell why that is happening?

Comment: Quick fix? 
Add overflow: hidden; to body.

The real issue?
Caused by your global "*" style of margin: 0; combined with the borders you applied to certain elements - basically the element I notice this on is <div id="main">: the element is 100% wide but you then add borders which increase it's width by 1px on each side making it wider than the page triggering the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Please add this styles for #menu ID

```
#menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #4E84FE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
}
```

If you want to remove the scroll bar please try this

```
#main {  
    border: none; 
}
```

Comment: I tried `body { overflow-x: hidden; }` and it worked. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Make the width of #main 99% and scrollbar will disappear. I don't know why but it will.

```
#main{width: 99%}
```